# android browser: user clicks "video file" link; results in new "server session"

Tags: android, video-streaming

I've been working with serving up video files to an android browser.

I've seen some behavior that I don't understand.

If the html has a video url in an anchor tag:

```
<a href="http://host.com/path/to/some/file.mp4">Video Here</a>
```

When the user clicks a link, (and android launches a separate 'video player' app), I see a new "session cookie" on the server side.

```
[19/May/2013:15:22:37 -0500] GET /pe/MediaDownload/10101302/30222/cheeravi.mp4  '' 200  bytes=122880 duration=7127 '499D09751C6C3040B80F8987EE630AB1' '-' 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.2.2; en-us; sdk Build/JB_MR1.1) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30' '-' '172.16.1.47' 'http://172.16.1.47:8080/pe/action/forums/displaythread?rootPostID=10101302&channelID=10&portalPageId=1016' '1:31'
[19/May/2013:15:22:42 -0500] GET /pe/MediaDownload/10101302/30222/cheeravi.mp4  '' 200  bytes=502185 duration=3962 'A9BE64F91CF0F9546DE5F2EC6021BC82' '-' 'stagefright/1.2 (Linux;Android 4.2.2)' '-' '172.16.1.47' 'null' '-'
```

The second entry has a different session id --i.e. different set of cookies.

In the second request, it is a "new session" and can't pass server side validation. (i.e. checking if the user has access to the resource)

**Questions:**

1) why two requests?
2) can I get the media player to pass in the same set of cookies, i.e. re-use the same session?

thanks